# Using ChromeDriver with WebDriverIO without Selenium

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, webdriver, webdriver-io

I want to drive my webdriverio tests with ChromeDriver, without going by Selenium. That should be [possible, it seems](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/getting-started), but I am not sure where to start.

I have tried starting up ChromeDriver like this

```
chromedriver
```

and then in another Window I have started up the `wdio` testrunner like this:

```
$(npm bin)/wdio
```

If doing nothing this will just get me

```
ERROR: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:4444
```

Changing the port in the `wdio.conf.js` to match the ChromeDriver's port 9515 gets me

```
ERROR: unknown command: wd/hub/session
```

I have tried adding `--url-base=wd/hub/session` to the chromedriver startup options, but it just changes the error to

```
ERROR: unhandled request
```

Still, no go. I have set the `services` property for wdio to `['chromedriver']` - but it does not seem to take effect.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[It turns out](https://github.com/atti187/wdio-chromedriver-service/issues/1) that I failed to follow *one vital bit* of information:

**`path: '/'`**

From the [docs](http://webdriver.io/guide/getstarted/configuration.html)

> path
>
> Path to WebDriver server.
>
> Type: String
>
> Default: /wd/hub

This is the address the Chromedriver is listening to.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use wdio-chromedriver-service. It was developed to be able to run Chromedriver without Selenium server.

Link to npm registry: https://www.npmjs.com/package/wdio-chromedriver-service.

Comment: that's what I am using. note the `services: ['chromedriver']` bit.

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice that.